# How to have 2 different schemas in one IOS project for 2 different URLs?

Tags: ios, swift, graphql, schema

Can I have multiple schemas in one single project for different URLs?. Using apollographql for API calls. but in one situation need to use a different URL and its different schema. But don't know how to configure it in build phases in Apollo CLI.

Comment: Yes you can. what is the issue?

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini How to download two different schema.json files into the project.   what and how the script should be added in Build Phase -> Apollo CLI to auto-download two different schema.json files with different names. I am currently following (https://www.apollographql.com/docs/ios/downloading-schema/) this tutorial to get schema.json download.

Comment: @AVR were you able to set up multiple schemas? I'm going through the same issue

Answer (score -1):

[image]

Copy your original Info.plist and name it for example Info_debug.plist

Then click on your project (the blue icon at the very top left of your file navigator) and go in the Build Settings > Packaging section, there you will find the item "Info.plist file" and if you made at least 2 different builds you should get a little arrow right to the left of this item: unfold it and you should be able to customize your plist file for every build... As shown on the attached screenshot.